# Flutter Reactive-BLE how to do OTA

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ota

I am trying to do an OTA Update on my bluetooth device. Therefor I got some gbl files, which I need to read out and send via flutter_reactive_ble to the bluetooth device. Does anyone of you know how to readout the gbl file and then convert it, that I can use writeCharacteristicWithResponse for this?

I am using this library: https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble

Comment: What are the requirements of your BLE device regarding OTA updates? I would assume you need to split the update file in multiple parts and send them, but this depends on your requirements.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for the response. Yeah I have to sure split the file in multiple parts. But I am struggeling to read the GBL file. Do you know how to read the GBL file as a byte array?

Comment: In case you need to send the full file without interpreting its content you should be able to read it like any other textfile and convert it to a byte array

Answer (score 0):

if the question is still up-to-date. I have a short answer.

1. read the file e.g. with the file handler plugin.
2. Split the file byte by byte into Uint8Lists. This depends to the device which you are sending the file. e.g. 244 byte / transmission.
   This means you send the first 244 bytes of the file, then the next 244 and so on.

OTA with flutter reactive ble.

1. you have to write a control bit to the device, which simple says "hey now I will start to send you the file." So write "0" in the specific characteristic.

   await flutterReactiveBle.writeCharacteristicWithResponse(characteristicControl, value: [0]);
2. than finish the file transmission with any kind of loop or so.

   flutterReactiveBle.writeCharacteristicWithoutResponse(characteristicData, value: tmpList);
3. at the end, write the same control bit characteristic again, but this time 3.

   flutterReactiveBle.writeCharacteristicWithResponse(characteristicControl, value: [3]);
4. reboot the device.

Keep in mind that the values of the control bit, OTAControlbitCharacteristic and OTADataCharacteristic can be different to yours.